# Extending function object

Tags: javascript, architecture

I have a `DraftForm` object handling behavior for a draft form, initially designed to be used in a specific dashboard page:

```
let DraftForm = (formSelector, $parent, url) => {
    let init = () => {
        // initialize form behavior...

        // initialize behavior specific to the page
        if (page == '1') initPageSpecific();
    };
    let initPageSpecific = () => {};

    return {
        load: () => {
            $.ajax(...).done(() => init());
        }
    }
};
```

However, now I'm looking into reusing this component so there are certain piecies of the original `init` function that are no longer relevant to a *generic* draft. For instance, when submitting it or closing the form, in the dashboard page we would refresh the list of drafts shown to the user. However, now that's no longer applicable after the extract the common functionality. I'm looking into the proper ways of extracting this functionality and rolling scenario-specific versions of the component.

How can I extend `DraftForm` to define new "subclasses" of this object? For instance, a `DashboardDraftForm` where `init` would call the parent function as well as page-specific behavior. Or also, `UserDraftForm` where you are in the user profile and want to send them an email.

The current approach of `page == '1'` is just bad design.

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing some info about the methods inside your DraftForm func

But internal methods can be arranged depending on your purposes (missing info):

```
let DraftForm = (formSelector, $parent, url) => {
    let init = () => {
        // initialize form behavior...

        // initialize behavior specific to the page
        if (page == '1') initPageSpecific();
    };
    let initPageSpecific = () => { };

    return {
        load: () => {
            // $.ajax(...).done(() => init());
        }
    }
};


var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();

var DraftFormBase = /** @class */ (function () {

    return DraftForm;
}());



var DashboardDraftForm = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(DashboardDraftForm, _super);
    function DashboardDraftForm(props) {
        return _super.call(this, props) || this;
    }
    DashboardDraftForm.prototype.init = function () {
        //do specific stuff
    };
    DashboardDraftForm.prototype.load = function () {
        //do specific stuff
    };
    return DashboardDraftForm;
}(DraftFormBase));

var c = new DashboardDraftForm({});
var data = c.load();


console.log(c);
```

Comment: I meant the opposite, "now" I meant to reuse that, not "not".

Comment: sorry you're right. I adjusted my answer. How to inherit / extend via javascript should be pretty clear. Via __extends() plus .prototype.*